# Short function to switch between innerHTML and textContent without full if else statement

Tags: javascript

This isn't a problem, more of a curiosity. I have an anonymous arrow function that writes data to the screen.

```js
const output = (message, selector, html=false) => {
  if (html) {
    selector.innerHTML += message;
  } else {
    selector.textContent += message;
  }
};
```

Pretty straightforward and easy to implement and use. It isn't too long, but I am curious if I can make a one line function; essentially collapsing the if the else statement into a ternary.

Something like this:

```js
const output = (message, selector, html=false) => selector.(html?innerHTML:textContent) = message;
```

Again, my current function works flawlessly and this is more of a curiosity.

The above example has been tried and failed. Additionally I tried the following, which failed, as I knew it would.

```js
const output = (message, selector, html=false) => selector.${(html?innerHTML:textContent)} = message;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```js
const output = (message, selector, html=false) => {
  selector[html ? 'innerHTML' : 'textContent'] += message;
};
```

Comment: Just posted something like that as a message.   But you might want to get rid of the `{}`

Comment: And putting it all on one line: `const output = (message, selector, html=false) => selector[html ? 'innerHTML' : 'textContent'] += message;`

Note that this type of code is _bad_. There is nothing wrong with the `if / else` version OP originally posted. Using the version above is only useful in "code golfing" type scenarios. You should not write this in an production-facing application.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you. @romellem, this is not part of a production site. I use this on my private dev server.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it one liner with simply doing this:

```
const output = (message, selector, html=false) => selector[html ? 'innerHTML' : 'textContent'] += message;
```

But it doesn't give more readability to your code.

I would suggest to use guard clause like this

```
const output = (message, selector, html = false) => {
  if (html) return (selector.innerHTML += message);
  selector.textContent += message;
};
```

Have some more reading at:

1. https://learningactors.com/javascript-guard-clauses-how-you-can-refactor-conditional-logic/
2. https://medium.com/@timothydan/javascript-guard-clauses-64b999e3240